# How to render data nested object from json (external api) with handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

If i want to render it (this data json return for one company)

```
 {
  "symbol": "BAC",
  "companyName": "Bank Of America Corp.",
  "primaryExchange": "NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE, INC.",
  "calculationPrice": "close",
  "open": 28.81,
  "openTime": 1607437801023,
  "openSource": "official",
  "close": 28.81,
  "closeTime": 1607461201852,
  "closeSource": "official",
  "high": 29.12,

}
```

I can access data above like this with handlebars. (It's work !)

```
<h4>LatestPrice <span class="badge bg-secondary">  {{stock.open}}    </span></h4>
<h4>PreviousClose <span class="badge bg-secondary">  {{ stock.close}}    </span></h4>
<h4>ChangePercent <span class="badge bg-secondary">  {{  stock.closeTime}}     </span></h4>
```

**And my question**

If i want to access specific propeties in nested object data below, such as i want to access stock.avgTotalVolume (for AMC Entertainment)
**How can i do that with handlebars ?**

```
[
 {
  avgTotalVolume: 96209223,
  calculationPrice: 'tops',
  companyName: 'AMC Entertainment Holdings Inc - Class A'
  
 } ,
 {
  avgTotalVolume: 81507563,
  calculationPrice: 'tops',
  companyName: 'Apple Inc',
  
 } ,
 {
  avgTotalVolume: 4160539,
  calculationPrice: 'tops',
  companyName: 'Helbiz Inc.',
 
 } ,
 {
  avgTotalVolume: 60408227,
  calculationPrice: 'tops',
  companyName: 'Ford Motor Co.',
 } ,
]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the `avgTotalVolume` for stock object at a particular index in your array, or do you want to loop through _all_ of the stock objects?

Comment: Yes, I want particular index in my array. How can i do that ?

Comment: You would do that like `{{stocks.[2].avgTotalVolume}}`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/k9bafcpg/

Comment: @76484 Hey Professor, It's working !! , I tried so long. how can i contact you ? , if i need some advice from you. Thank sir.

Comment: I think you should just post your questions here in StackOverflow and I or someone else will help if possible.

Comment: @76484 Thank sir.

Comment: I suppose if you ever had code in GitHub that you wanted reviewed you could add me (link in profile) and I could possibly take a look.

Comment: @76484 Thank you so much.