# Handlebars: Is it possible to fetch an object from array by property value?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there a way to fetch an object from array by property value with handebars?

Data:

```
food: [
  { fruit: 'apple', color: 'red' },
  { fruit: 'pear',  color: 'yellow' }
]
```

Imaginary handlebars usage:

```
{{ food[@fruit:apple].color }}
```

Is something like this available? Or do I need to create and register a custom helper?

Comment: `{{ food.find(item => item.fruit === 'apple').color }}`

Comment: If you want to get an item from your array at a known index, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271618/how-to-render-data-nested-object-from-json-external-api-with-handlebars#comment122436011_69271618, but if you want to _filter_ your array you will need to create a custom helper.